# Name of current section/figure

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm looking for a LaTeX command, say `\foo`, which expands to the type of section I'm in. In the following, the first `\foo` should expand to "Section", the second to "Subsection", and the third one to "Figure":

```
\section{aaa}
Hello \foo

\subsection{bbb}
Hello \foo

\begin{figure}
  whatever
  \caption{bla \foo}
\end{figure}
```

I'd like to have this to build a labeling package which knows where the label comes from, i.e., a `\label{R4wmVP}` inside a figure would make `\ref{R4wmVP}` print "Figure \thefigure". The benefit is that after making a section a subsection (or chapter), all references change automatically.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the package `hyperref` with the commands `autoref` and `nameref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{aaa}\label{sec:1}
Hello \autoref{sec:1}\qquad\nameref{sec:1}

\subsection{bbb}\label{subsec:1}
Hello \autoref{subsec:1}\qquad\nameref{subsec:1}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 whatever
 \caption{bla}\label{fig:1}
 \end{figure}

 \autoref{fig:1}\qquad\nameref{fig:1}

\end{document}
```

The code above produce the following result:

[image]

In relation to the comments here an example without `hyperref` by using `nameref` and `cleveref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{aaa}\label{sec:1}
Hello \nameref{sec:1}\qquad\cref{sec:1}\qquad\namecref{sec:1}

\subsection{bbb}\label{subsec:1}
Hello \nameref{subsec:1}\qquad\cref{subsec:1}\qquad\namecref{subsec:1}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 whatever
 \caption{bla}\label{fig:1}
 \end{figure}

\nameref{fig:1}\qquad\cref{fig:1}\qquad\namecref{fig:1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want to use hyperref, just use the [`nameref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref) directly

Comment: @Seamus: I forgot this. If you are agree, I expand my post.

Comment: yes that's fine. Go ahead.

Comment: Be aware that this does'nt work with unnumbered section or subsection. See this for more informations: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35882/67664