# Reference to an unnumbered section

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing, numbering

I am writing a thesis with document class **report** and I am using **hyperref**.
My structure is the following:

```
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
    \subsection{First sub section}
        \subsubsection*{My Section}
```

However, I'd like to reference the `\subsubsection` with their name, but I don't want to number them (at all in the whole document). For example, I could write (using `\nameref` command):

In Section "My Section" we saw that...

However, if I add label to that section, it references to the subsection (First sub section). This is what I have:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{My title}
\subsubsection*{My title}
\label{sec:mysection}
```

Moving `\label` command between `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline` makes it reference to the previous subsection. How could I make it refer to the unnumbered subsubsection?

Comment: subsubsections aren't numbered by default (or are they in report?). Either way, if you don't want to number them throughout you can set the `secnumdepth` counter to `2`. This will cause only parts, chapters, and sections to be numbered. It allows you to write `\subsubsection` instead of the starred variant. If you then later decide that you *do* want to number them, the change is limited to the counter instead of removing `*` throughout your document. You can use the `nameref` package to reference sections by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the starred version the reference counter is not updated. If you don't want numbering below subsection, just change the `secnumdepth` counter. The following code demonstrates this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection 1}
  \label{subsubsec:1}
  This should be unnumbered.
\subsubsection{subsubsection 2}
  See subsubsection~\nameref{subsubsec:1}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: referencing unnumbered subsubsection by name]

Comment: Actually, setting `secnumdepth` is unnecessary as it's default value is 2.

Comment: Yeah, I already mentioned that in my comment. Just wasn't sure if this was also the case in the report class, since I never really use this class.

Comment: Indeed so :) I'd like to add, that when referencing something unnumbered, it would be very helpful to the reader to include a page reference using `\pageref{subsubsec:1}`. See the package `varioref` where `\vpageref{subsubsec:1}` results in something akin `on the preceding page` instead of a page number where appropriate.

Comment: Works like a dream, thanks. Nice thing with `\hyperref` is that it already includes `\nameref` and creates links to the actual paragraph, but indeed pageref makes it more usable for the readers of printed version. I might have a non-standard report class but it needed this secnumdepth setting. But now it's working correctly!

Comment: TLDR: insteaf of \ref, use \nameref