# Is there a command that expands to the current section name?

Tags: sectioning

**Is there a command that expands to the current section name (which I can then use with `\index{}`)?**

This is similar to [Name of current section/figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25563/name-of-current-section-figure), but I like to get the name of the section instead of the current type, also `\nameref{}` doesn't work when using index. I tried

```
\label{sec:foo} \index{\nameref{sec:foo}}
```

which will show the current section name in Index, but it's out of order with the other non-`\nameref{}` Index entries. I believe that's because they are hyperlinked.

Comment: Dirty hack: add `\let\oldsection\section`, `\def\section#1#{\sectionii{#1}}\def\sectionii#1#2{\def\currsecname{#2}\oldsection#1{#2}}` to your preamble; then in each section `\currsecname` holds the name of the current section.

Comment: @Bruno: did not work for me :( Undefinied control sequenz

Comment: @Megachip Which control sequence is undefined?  Maybe you have a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\indexref}[1]{%
  \sbox0{\nameref{#1}}%
  \expandafter\index\expandafter{\GetTitleStringResult}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{x}\indexref{x}
\end{document}
```

According to the documentation of `nameref.sty`, the title to which `\label{x}` refers is stored in the macro `\GetTitleStringResult` (globally). So we emit `\nameref{x}` in a box just to get the title and expand the macro containing the title before applying `\index`.

Comment: Thanks a log egreg, this does work! But there is now way to get the current section name from a command, so that I could avoid the detour with `\label{}` and `\nameref{}`?

Comment: You might redefine `\section`, but it's tedious; this has the merit to work with *any* sectional level.

Comment: You should be able to define `\newcommand\labelandindex[1]{\label{#1}\indexref{#1}` to at least avoid writing everything twice, shouldn't you?